# Regular expression in notepad++ or other editors

Tags: regex, notepad++

Can anybody help me create a regular expression for find and replace?

Original statement

```
rb[10];

rf[10];

eg[10];
```

replace with

```
rb[10-1];

rf[10-1];

eg[10];
```

The number "10" can vary between 1 to 500.

I only want to change the variables rf and rb, and leave eg unchanged. Also, I only want to modify the numbers between '[]' and add '-1' to that number. The variables rf, rb ,eg can be anywhere in the line, not necessarily at the start or the end of the line.

As you all can see I am modifying a Fortran code to C code. I only want to change array indices and leave everything unchanged.

Comment: And what is the rule? Have you tried anything yet for us to see what you really are after?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\b(rb|rf)\[(\d+)\]
```

And replace with `$1[$2-1]`.

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary (the preceding char should be a non-word one or start of line)
- `(rb|rf)`  -  Group 1 (later referred to as `$1` in the replacement pattern) capturing either `rb` or `rf` (note `r[bf]` is a much better way of writing it)
- `\[` - a literal `[` symbol
- `(\d+)` -  Group 2 (later referred to as `$2` in the replacement pattern) capturing 1 or more digits (if you want to match a specific range from `1` to `500` only, replace `\d+` with `(?:500|[1-4]?\d{2}|[1-9])`)
- `\]` - a literal `]` symbol

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pretty easy regex like this:

```
(\d+)
```

And a replacement string with `\1-1`

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yP7uL6/1)**

[image]

Update: for your comments, you can use a regex like this (with the same replacement string):

```
(r[bf]\[\d+)
```

Comment: I wanted to change that only for variable rf and rb. I want leave the variable eg unchanged. Is there a way I can specify that in the regular expression.

Comment: Also is there a way I can create a regular expression to select the text between '[]' and replace the text with '-1' added to it.

Comment: As you can tell I am converting a fortran code to a C code. I only want to change the array indices and leave all the other numbers unchanged.

Comment: @user3357091, you could use this regex `(r[bf]\[\d+)`